# Concrete example for one forms.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

I'm reading about k-forms right now but am still quite confused about the different notations, which is why I'm trying to look at a concrete example. Let's say we have a one-form in three-dimensions: $\omega(x) = dx + 2dy - 4dz$, and for example the vector $\vec{a} = (1,1,1)$, how would I compute $\omega(\vec{a})$? Is that a reasonable question to ask? Sorry if it's confusing, but I'm really just trying to make sense of this by self study which is quite hard.

Comment: You might find [my YouTube lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5I-Eyk8l9FHdJUd9UujGcvumjCFPHbrd) helpful. Note that there is a complete version of the first differential forms lecture at the very bottom of the long list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form is $\omega = \,dx + 2 \,dy - 4 \,dz$ and your tangent vector at the point $a$ is $t_a = (1,1,1)$, then you can think about each of the $\,dx, \,dy,  \,dz$ as projecting onto the corresponding components of the tangent vector.

In your example,
\begin{align*} 
\omega(t_a) &= \,dx(1,1,1) + 2 \cdot \,dy (1,1,1) - 4 \,dz(1,1,1) \\
&= 1 + 2 \cdot 1 - 4 \cdot 1 \\
&= -1
\end{align*}

Let's look at another example.  If your point is $a = (1,2,3)$ and your tangent vector at $a$ is $t_a = (3,2,1)$ and we define $\omega = x \,dx + 2y^2 \,dy - 3xz \,dz$, then
\begin{align*}
\omega(t_a) &= 1 \,dx (3,2,1) + 2(2)^2 \,dy(3,2,1) - 3 \cdot 1 \cdot 3 \,dz (3,2,1) \\
&= 1 \cdot 3 + 8 \cdot 2 - 9 \cdot 1 \\
&=10.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for that really quick and great answer. Since I can't seem to find an example that basic, could you also tell me how I would wedge the two $\omega_1$ and  $\omega_2$ from above?

Comment: Sure thing:  note that $\,dx \wedge \,dx = 0$.  Then with $\omega_1 = \,dx + 2 \,dy - 4 \,dz$ and $\omega_2 = x \,dx + 2y^2 \,dy - 3xz \,dz$, we have: $\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 = x \,dx \wedge  \,dx + 2x \,dy \wedge \,dx - 4x \,dz \wedge \,dx + 2y^2 \,dx \wedge \,dy + 4y^2 \,dy \wedge \,dy - 8y^2 \,dz \wedge \,dy - 3xz \,dx \wedge \,dz -  6xz \,dy \wedge \,dz + 12xz \,dz \wedge \,dz$.

Comment: Thanks, great help.